# BigTable Scan withStopRow inclusive issue

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Maybe I am mistaken,  but it seems that the "inclusive" boolean on the scan method is not working. Below, I would expect the scan to include "row3" because I have withStopRow("row3".getBytes(), true)), however, I only scan into row2.

```
Output Received:   
Row: row1
Row: row2
```

pom below...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
    <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.x-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java Code:
    Table table = conn.getTable(TABLE_NAME);

```
table.put(new Put("row1".getBytes()).addColumn("fam".getBytes(), "qual".getBytes(), "val".getBytes()));
table.put(new Put("row2".getBytes()).addColumn("fam".getBytes(), "qual".getBytes(), "val".getBytes()));
table.put(new Put("row3".getBytes()).addColumn("fam".getBytes(), "qual".getBytes(), "val".getBytes()));

for (Result r : table.getScanner(new Scan().withStartRow("row1".getBytes()).withStopRow("row3".getBytes(), true))) {
        System.out.println(("Row: " + new String(r.getRow())));
    }
```

Comment: Can you please raise a bug on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues?  We can fix this problem and release a 1.4.1 with this change

Comment: Just created an issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bug acknowledged, ref comment above.  Issue created in GitHub

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1850